# CCRenderTexture and CCDirector render differently?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

i wanted to use CCRenderTexture in my project because i have a lot of CCLabelBMFont that are mostly static. Adding them all to my Scene caused some performance issues (Yes you can use BatchNotes etc. but it didnt really help). So I rendered them into a single Texture which increased the performance significantly! But the problem is that the rendered texture and the directly rendered node look different. I have no idea why!

I created a cocos2d-sample project and and created this:

```
CCSprite* testImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"N.png"];
testImage.position = ccp(100,100);
CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:786 height:1024];
[rt beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];
[testImage visit];
[rt end];
CCSprite* renderedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];
renderedSprite.position = ccp(386,512);
// Flip because CCRenderTexture is flipped
renderedSprite.flipY = YES;
// Add normal node an the rendered sprite
testImage.position = ccp(130,100);
[self addChild:testImage];
[self addChild:renderedSprite];
```

The results look like this:
[image: The texture has less glow]

How can this be? How can i make them look the same?
The N on the right is the sprite added the "normal" way and it is displayed correctly. The N on the left is the texture.

Edit:
i found [this tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/#rendertexturesprite) which hints that the blend functions are different. so can i am looking for the correct function to make them look the same.

Comment: How did you do the batch drawing of bitmap font labels?

Comment: I only tried to do it, but it didnt work as i planned, since bmFontLabels are no sprites and cannot be added to the batchnode. i tried to put each one into a sprite but that gave me the whole fontmap. im sure there is a way to do this correctly but i don't really know how.

Comment: Ok, just a quick follow up:
I did manage to put multiple single letters into one big render texture and the performance is very good!!
The idea is to remove the letters from the label and add them to your batch node, which has, obviously the same texture as the label.
I am able to render single animations on 500 letters on a first gen iPad with 60 frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution!
I used [this example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture) to create the sprite but when i looked into the cocos2d-manual again i saw, that you can add the CCRenderTexture directly to your scene. Thats what i did and it solved the problem!

So the correct code should be:

```
CCSprite* testImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"N.png"];
testImage.position = ccp(100,100);
CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:786 height:1024];
[rt begin];
[testImage visit];
[rt end];
rt.position = ccp(386,512);
// Add normal node an the rendered sprite
testImage.position = ccp(130,100);
[self addChild:testImage];
[self addChild:rt];
```

Comment: Why are you adding testImage to the scene as well? It's already in the rendertexture that means "N" gets rendered twice.

Comment: yes i just added it for test purposes, so you can see the difference in the screenshot